# get all rows in single query with multiple id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a `asset_request` table with fields `id` and `request_id`.
I want to select multiple rows with specific ids.

`$ids = $request->ids // 5,6`

I want to select only rows with ids of 5 and 6 in request table

```
$ids = $request->ids;
$asset_request = asset_request::whereIn('id',array($ids))->first(); //gets only 6th row.
```

I need to get all rows matching the given ids.

Comment: Try `->get();`!! Like: `$asset_requst=asset_request::whereIn('id',array($ids))->get();`

Comment: can you share your html file?

Comment: @james, why would you need the html file? It's a controller query...

Comment: because I can't imagine how your code works and I'm not really sure about your problem. I only know the reason why you can get only 6th row,, because you use `first()`.. if you want to get more than one row of data, you have to use `get()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify after a chat discussion with the Op:

The Op was passing back a string request, therefore, the Op needed to change the following:

```
$id = $request->id;

$ids = str_split(str_replace(',', '', $id));

$asset_request = asset_request::whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
```

Comment: $id=array($request->ids);  $asset_requst=asset_request::whereIn('id',$id)->get(); Still getting one row.What I did wrong

Comment: @user3386779, above the query do `dd($ids)` and tell me how many it's passing back.

Comment: dd($ids) is "6,5"

Comment: @User3386779, and it's passing back as what, an array?

Comment: select * from `asset_request` where `id` in (6,5) it displays 2 rows in php mysql but not in application

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168625/discussion-between-user3386779-and-option).

Answer (score 1):

First you are calling the `first` method which will return only the first row matched.
You need to call `get` method to get all rows matched.

Secondly if you are sending `ids` as a comma separated string you need to convert it to array using `explode`.

```
$ids = $request->ids;
$asset_requst = asset_request::whereIn('id', explode(",", $ids))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('asset_request')
           ->whereIn('id', (array) $request->ids)
           ->get();
```

or

```
TableModel::whereIn('id', (array) $request->ids)->get();
```

Comment: The Op is fetching via $request not hardcoding the ID's in.

Comment: @Option **$request->ids** this is string or array?

Comment: This was partially the issue the op was having they wasn't passing back as an array, therefore, it needed to be answered as well.

Comment: $request->ids an array